# Centos7 firewall not blocking ports by default

Tags: centos7, firewalld, docker-compose

**Problem:**
MySQL port 3306 is open and publicly accessible. I want to close it.

**Firewall status**

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --state
running
```

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client https http
  ports: 80/tcp 443/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

```
$ nmap IP
Starting Nmap 7.70 
..cut..
Host is up (0.47s latency).
Not shown: 994 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   closed ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
3306/tcp open   mysql
```

Why is port 3306 open? Why aren't the ports closed by default?

Comment: Do you run the `nmap` on the same host?

Comment: No, the issue is with the server, I'm runing nmap from my local computer.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out.

The port 3306 was exposed with **docker** and [docker bypasses typical iptables rules](https://uilicious.com/blog/5-fatal-docker-gotchas-for-new-users/). So .. yeah.

The solution was to change `docker-composer.yml` configuration from

```
ports:
 - 3306:3306
```

to

```
expose:
 - 3306
```

where [expose will not expose the port publicly, only to other containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883938/402472).